# Django: How can I provide different users a different subset of options for the same ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-admin

## The Question:

How can I provide different users a different subset of options for the same ManyToManyField in the admin, and have each user's selections only affect their options?

## The Scenario:

I am building an interactive map web app. There can be many Maps. There can be many MapItems.
MapItems can be on many Maps and Maps can have many Map Items. Thus a ManyToMany relationship.

Each Map has an owner, and I want only the owner of a Map to be able to add or remove MapItems from his/her Map.

Here are the relevant parts of my models:

```
class Map(models.Model):
    # Omit
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)

class MapItem(models.Model):
    # Omit
    map = models.ManyToManyField(Map, default=None, blank=True)
```

MapItem.map is represented by a `<select>` on the MapItem admin interface:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="id_map" name="map">
  <option value="1">Bob's Map</option>
  <option value="2">Sally's Map</option>
</select>
```

I want Bob to only have the option to select/deselect Bob's Map and not even see Sally's Map as an option.

I have been able to filter the options that are displayed in the admin `<select>` widget by overriding get_form() on the ModelAdmin.

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    kwargs['form'] = MapItemAdminForm
    form = super(MapItemAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['map'].queryset = form.base_fields['map'].queryset.filter(Q(owner=request.user) | Q(groups__in=request.user.groups.all()))
    return form
```

So far so good. This gives me a select with only the desired options:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="id_map" name="map">
  <option value="1">Bob's Map</option>
</select>
```

The problem comes in when Bob saves. When Bob saves, it wipes out any saved value for Sally's Map. So if Sally's Map was selected, when Bob saves (even though Bob can't see it), Sally's Map gets deselected.

Is there a better approach to this problem? Is there a way to ensure that unchanged values (like Sally's Map being selected) persist on save?

Comment: You need to validate the input data and give an error if trying to save invalid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lufte's answer was close, but not quite what I needed. It did put me on the right scent though. Here is my solution:

`save_model` is great for tweaking the values of fields that are not ManyToMany. However, ManyToMany fields
are not able to be affected in this method, as whatever changes made [will be cleared prior to being saved](http://timonweb.com/posts/many-to-many-field-save-method-and-the-django-admin/).

`save_related`, on the other hand, is just what I needed. I was able to determine which Maps my user should be able to affect in `get_form` and pass any others on to be saved in `save_related`. [DOCS.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related)

Here's some code for reference:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
      form = super(MapItemAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

      # Filter already selected maps
      # and create a list of map current user can't touch
      self.existing_maps = [m.id for m in obj.map.all() \
      if not m.owner == request.user and not \
      m.groups.filter(id__in=request.user.groups.all())]

      # Filter the options that will be displayed in the admin <select>
      form.base_fields['map'].queryset = \
      form.base_fields['map'].queryset.filter(Q(owner=request.user) \
      | Q(groups__in=request.user.groups.all()))
      return form

  def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
      super(MapItemAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)

      # Re-add any previously selected maps that the current user can't touch
      for em in self.existing_maps:
          form.instance.map.add(em)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the ModelAdmin's `save_model` method.

In it, you will need to delete all relations that belong to the current user (instead of deleting all relations which is the current behavior) and save all submitted relations (which you know belong to the current user because you filtered the options, but you should probably re-validate this in a previous step because HTTP requests can be tampered with) again.